# Модель учебной ЭВМ Жмакина

Tags: ассемблер

Требуется поиск в массиве минимального положительное число. n = 14! Помогите сделать, вот пример кода:

```
    rd #50       ; R0 - указатель на начало массива
    wr r0
    rd #6        ; R1 - длина массива
    wr r1
    rd #0        ; R2 - результат
    wr r2
m1:              ; цикл сравнений
    rd @r0+      ; автоинкрементное чтение элемента
    wr r3        ; сохранение элемента
    sub #1       ; проверка знака
    js next      ; неположительный - перейти к следующему
    rd r2        ; проверка текущего минимума
    sub #1
    jns NotFirst ; найден первый отрицательный элемент?
    mov r2,r3    ; да - сохранить его как минимальный
    jrnz r1,m1   ; и продолжить цикл
NotFirst:        ; нет - сравнить с минимумом
    rd r3
    sub r2
    jns next     ; если не меньше - продолжить цикл
    mov r2,r3    ; иначе - обновить минимум
next:
    jrnz r1,m1   ; проверка счётчика цикла

    rd r2        ; загрузка
    out          ; и вывод результата
    hlt
```

Comment: Офф топ, но гораздо проще, написать на С и попросить GCC/clang перевести в asm, и потом уже оптимизировать и по убирать лишнее на ваш взгляд.

Comment: @NewView где тут по вашему оффтопик? Ассемблер тоже язык как ни как.

Comment: Офтоп, не писать самостоятельно, а преобразовать С код в асм :) это я про свой совет, а не про вопрос автора

Comment: @NewView, сомневаюсь, что GCC/clang умеют генерировать ассемблер для "учебной модели ЭВМ Жмакина". Код в вопросе - это явно не ассемблер архитектуры x86.